# Forward a form submission in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a `HTML` webform (**NOT** asp.net webform) that submits its form to an `aspx` script.

On the `aspx` script, I'd like to simply forward the form submission to a different form processing script. (after checking just one or two things using `Request.Form["variable"]`)

What is the simplest way to forward the original html page's form submission?

```
Currently:
html1 -> aspx1 -> html2

Desired:
html1 -> aspx1 -> aspx2 -> html2
```

Comment: Did any of these answers help you with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

**I would attempt to solve this problem in the following fashion**

1. Create a Repeater
2. Set the Request.Form as the datasource of the repeater. If this does not work, i would convert Request.Form into a suitable datastructure, such as a Dictionary or Datatable for binding to the Repeater
3. Each repeater item would have an input tag, and would receive the appropriate name/id and value. I would not use a server-control input tag. I would emit the string in a more organic fashion.
4. I would then post to the second aspx page.

The purpose of the repeater is to build an equivalent Form NameValueCollection for processing on the second aspx page.

**References**

- [Cross Page Postback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)
- [Posting to another page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx)
- [Binding a Dictionary to a Repeater](http://forums.asp.net/p/1184360/2020322.aspx)
- [Binding Dictionary to DropDownList](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2006/12/19/101546.aspx) - (Note, "Key", "Value")

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about simplest way then it is using session variable.
Just save your form values to the session and then you can access it anywhere in your application during the particular session.

So I would have my aspx1 page something like this

```
// ASPX1 page's Page_Load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.Form["variable"] == "SomeValue")//some condition
   {
      // save these values to session so that they will
      // be available when I will be in aspx2 page
      Session["FormValues"] = Request.Form;

      Response.Redirect("ASPX2.aspx"); // your aspx2 page's link

   }

}
```

And aspx2 page something like this

```
// ASPX2 page's Page_Load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // form values from aspx1 page
   NameValueCollection formValuesCollection = 
                          (NameValueCollection)Session["FormValues"];

   string variableValue = formValuesCollection["variable"];

   // some processing using form values from aspx1 page

   Response.Redirect("HTML2.html");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatley I can't use this approach as I don't control the code for the 2nd form processing script